# How to use jinja template in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, jinja2

I've pyspark df like below:

```
FirstName  LastName  Score
Hello      World     [('Math', 90), ('Eng', 80)]
ABC        XYZ       [('Math', 90)]
```

The column `Score` is nothing but `struct` type in Spark which looks like below:

```
[Row(sub='Math', score=90), Row(sub='Eng', score=80)]
```

I want this `Score` column as Score_HTML.
Expected output be like:

```
FirstName  LastName  Score_HTML
Hello      World     "<b>FullName:</b>Hello World <br><br> <table border="1"><tr><td>Sub</td><td>Score</td></tr><tr><td>Math</td><td>90</td></tr><tr><td>Eng</td><td>80</td></tr></table>"
ABC        XYZ       "<b>FullName:</b>ABC XYZ <br><br> <table border="1"><tr><td>Sub</td><td>Score</td></tr><tr><td>Math</td><td>90</td></tr></table>"
```

How can I achieve this using `Jinja` template.

I even tried to convert to Pandas DF from Spark, and then apply Jinja template like below:

```
import jinja2
template = environment.from_string(
   """
   <b>FullName:</b>{{ FirstName }} {{ LastName }} </br></br>
   <table border="1"><tr><td>Sub</td><td>Score</td></tr><tr>
   {% for value in df['Score'] %}
      <td>"{{ value['sub'] }}"</td><td>"{{ value['score'] }}"</td>
   {% endfor %}
   </tr></table>
   """
)

df['Score_HTML'] = template.render(FirstName=df['FirstName'], LastName=df['FirstName']) ???
```

Need help to define Jinja template and use it in DF [either SparkDF or PandasDF] to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `mapInPandas` method to render the jinja template for each row of spark dataframe

```
from jinja2 import Template

TEMPLATE =  """
<b>FullName:</b>{{ FirstName }} {{ LastName }} </br></br>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Sub</td>
        <td>Score</td>
    </tr>
    {% for s in Score %}
    <tr>
        <td>"{{ s['sub'] }}"</td>
        <td>"{{ s['score'] }}"</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
"""

def render(iterator):
    template = Template(TEMPLATE)
    for chunk in iterator:
        chunk['Score'] = chunk.apply(lambda r:
                                     template.render(**r), axis=1)
        yield chunk


df1 = df.mapInPandas(render, schema="FirstName string, LastName string, Score string")
```

---

```
df1.show()

+---------+--------+--------------------+
|FirstName|LastName|               Score|
+---------+--------+--------------------+
|    Hello|   World|\n<b>FullName:</b...|
|      ABC|     XYZ|\n<b>FullName:</b...|
+---------+--------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for soln. I solved in similar way but by converting to Pandas DF, and ```apply``` func.

Answer (score 0):

Soln:

```
from jinja2 import Template

def calc(row):
    TEMPLATE = """
    <b>FullName:</b>{{ FirstName }} {{ LastName }} </br></br>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Sub</td>
            <td>Score</td>
        </tr>
        {% for s in Score %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ s['sub'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ s['marks'] }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    """
    TEMPLATE = TEMPLATE.replace("\n", "")
    template = Template(TEMPLATE)
    return template.render(**row)

df = df.toPandas() # Convert SparkDF to Pandas
df['Score_HTML'] = df.apply(calc, axis=1)
```

Comment: if the dataframe is big then mapInPandas will be faster since it uses cores effectively.